# ASP.NET MVC 3 override Html.BeginForm

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, validation

I have some validation Javascript files which all pages that use a form should include. The idea is to somehow override `Html.BeginForm` and in that override add the required Javascript to my `ResourceManager` (which will eventually write all references to HTML).

Can I override Html.BeginForm or is the only option to create another ExtensionMethod like `Html.MyBeginForm` which does the JS include stuff and then calls the original `BeginForm`?

Answer (score 0):

> Can I override Html.BeginForm or is the only option to create another
>   ExtensionMethod like Html.MyBeginForm

You cannot override the output of Html.BeginForm. You will have to write a custom extension method. Or better yet, use unobtrusive javascript to attach custom logic to your form. Html5 data-* attributes are an excellent way to attach metadata to a DOM element that could be unobtrusively exploited by javascript using the [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) function. It's the way unobtrusive client side validation and unobtrusive AJAX work in ASp.NET MVC.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to override anything as long as you include your javascript in your master (or _Layout.cshtml or _Layout.vbhtml) file. Unobtrusive ajax is probably the better way to go though. Just attach various properties to the form using the appropriate overload.

If you want to only attach the javascript files to views that have forms you can include conditional sections in your master, or simply choose a different master based on the category in question.

Masters can be in other masters. You can have a master for forms and a master for non-forms. Both can use a common base master that contains your layout information.

Comment: Yes I am using the unobtrusive scripts, the thing is that I dont want to include these scripts on every page, just on the pages that have a FORM element.